How to handle date and time in React based on a fixed time zone (tank location) instead of the user's browser time zone?
I am working in the oil and gas industry, where our application’s primary functionality is to store tank measurements. Our current approach uses the browser’s time zone when capturing and storing these measurements. However, our team has decided to switch to using the tank location’s time zone instead of the user’s local time zone.
We are using React as our frontend library. In our app, we heavily rely on new Date() for date-related operations, and we’ve written all our date conversion logic based on new Date(). However, if we switch to using the tank’s location time zone, using new Date() doesn’t seem viable anymore, as it depends on the user's local time zone.
The requirement is that the application should always use the tank’s location time zone, regardless of the user's actual location. I’d prefer to achieve this without relying on external libraries. How can I handle this scenario in plain JavaScript? Specifically:
1.How can I manage and convert dates to a fixed time zone (the tank’s location)?
2.What are the best practices to handle this purely with JavaScript?
3.How should I handle date pickers and time inputs so that they reflect and store dates in the tank’s location time zone?
export function getDateAfterSpecificMonth(monthCount: number, date: any) {
    date = new Date(date)
    // get the target year, month, date
    const year = date.getFullYear() + Math.trunc(monthCount / 12)
    const month = date.getMonth() + monthCount % 12
    let day = date.getDate()
    if (day > 27) {   // get a valid date
        const lastDateofMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate()
        day = Math.min(day, lastDateofMonth)
    }
    return new Date(year, month, day)
};

export function getDateBeforeSpecificMonth(monthCount: number, date: any) {
    date = new Date(date)
    // get the target year, month, date
    const year = date.getFullYear() - Math.trunc(monthCount / 12)
    const month = date.getMonth() - monthCount % 12
    let day = date.getDate()
    if (day > 27) {   // get a valid date
        const lastDateofMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate()
        day = Math.min(day, lastDateofMonth)
    }
    return new Date(year, month, day)
};

     <Row>
                <Col md={12} className="mb-3">
                    <CustomDatePicker
                        displayBlock={true}
                        className="inerg-text-primary me-1"
                        defaultType={filterState.type}
                        defaultDate={filterState.date}
                        theme={theme}
                        valueCallBack={(val: any, type: any, typeChange: any) => {
                            updateCustomDate(val, type, typeChange)
                        }}
                        options={customDateOptions.bulkEntry}
                        dateRange={dateRange}
                    />
                </Col>
     </Row>

I’ve been exploring various approaches, including manually adjusting dates using JavaScript’s built-in Date and Intl objects. However, I’m trying to gather different methods to understand the best way to consistently apply the tank’s location time zone across the application. I’m looking for a reliable approach that’s easy to maintain and doesn’t require external libraries.
I'm looking to create a custom date object, similar to new Date(), that retains all the methods and functionalities of the native Date object but operates based on a specified time zone rather than the browser's default time zone.
new Date(); // Native behavior using browser time zone.  
new customDate(); // Desired behavior using a specified time zone.


Do you want to use the tank's location for input of dates, or just for display? date = new Date(date) doesn't seem like a good idea unless you know exactly what date is (date: any indicates significant uncertainty).

It is generally advisable to store all your dates in UNIX epoch time, or in ISO 8601 timestamps (which is what new Date() also uses), and only convert them to timezone specific formats only when you want to display them to your users.
The standard format always leaves room for timezone specific details to change as and when requirements change. And also allows you to make use of libraries which directly make use of dates directly.
If you choose to go this route, you can just make changes to all .toString() functions you use like so:
Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString = function(locale = 'en-IN', options = {}) {
    options.timeZone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
    return this.toLocaleTimeString(locale, options);
}


If you already have values stored in your specific timezone format, I would still advise you to see if it is possible to change them throughout. But if this is not possible, and you must read your dates in your specific timezone format, you could write a wrapper around the date library to read dates in specific formats:
class DateIST extends Date {
    constructor(dateInput) {
        if (dateInput) {
            // Create the Date object and adjust to IST
            super(dateInput);
            this.setTime(this.getTime() + 5.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        } else {
            // No input means use the current date/time
            super();
            this.setTime(this.getTime() + 5.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        }
    }
}

Note: I have used IST (UTC+0530) through out the examples.
